# What's the difference in changing application.js vs config.assets.precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm studying assets precompile and I'm confused.

Let' say I created a new application like `rails new dummy`.

This is the generated `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

It says `This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js`. It's still clear up to this point, but I found out that there's another configuration that we can set under `config/application.rb`: `config.assets.precompile << \some_regex\`.

Now I'm unclear what's the difference between changing `application.js` vs `config.assets.precompile` for selecting what to be compiled.

I feel like I'm missing the bigger picture here, can someone help to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application.js file is for Javascript, as the name suggests. Because of the lines below in the file, jquery, jquery_ujs, turbolinks javascript library, and every Javascript files in your /app/assets/javascripts folder will be pre-compiled.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

You can use the "config.assets.precompile" to add other things to be pre-compiled such as font files and other files that are not recognized by Rails by default. You can use it to include javascript files as well. But, such needs are rare.

An example of it would be....

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

I hope this makes sense.